# is it possible to covert string expression's result to a int?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int a;
    string exp1,exp2,sign2,dec2,dec3;
    char sign;
    float op1=0,op2=0,answer=0,op3=0,exper1=0,exper2=0;
    string dec,clear;
     
    /*----------------------------------------------section of choices----------------------------------------------*/
    cout<<"Enter the number for desired operation\n"<<endl;                                  
    cout<<"Enter '1' for arithmetic operations "<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter '2' for increment/decrement operations"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter '3' for logical operations"<<endl;       
    cin>>a;
       
    /*----------------------------------------------section of Arithmetic operators----------------------------------------------*/
restart:
      
    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:                                                   
        cout<<"Section of Arithmetic opearators\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"enter first operand\n";
        cin>>op1;
        
        cout<<"Enter operator\n";
        cin>>sign;
        
        cout<<"Enter second operand\n";
        cin>>op2;
        
        cout<<"if you want to Start calculation press small 's'\ntype 'end' to end programe\n";
        cin>>dec;
        
        if(dec=="s")
        {
            goto start;
        }
        else
        {
            goto end;
        }
        
start: 
        switch (sign)
        {
        case '+':
            answer=op1+op2;
            break;
    
        case '-':
            answer=op1-op2;
            break;
    
        case '*':
            answer=op1*op2;
            break;
    
        case '/':
            answer=op1/op2;
            break;
    
        case '=':
            answer=op1=op2;
            break;
    
        case '>':
            answer=op1>op2;
            if (answer==0)
            {
                cout<<"the expression evaluates to fales\n";
            }
            cout<<"the expression evaluates to true\n";
            
            break;
    
        case '<':
            answer=op1<op2;
            if (answer==0)
            {
                cout<<"the expression evaluates to fales\n";
            }
            cout<<"the expression evaluates to ture\n";
            
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Enter a valid arithmetic operator!\n";
        }
        cout<<"the answer to the operation is "<<answer<<"\n\n\n<<"<<flush;
        cout<<"Press 'c' to clear screen and do more operations\n Enter end to end programe\n";
        cin>>clear;
        if (clear=="c")
        {
            system("cls");
            goto restart;
        }
        exit(0);        
        
        break;
    
    /*----------------------------------------------Increment/Decrement operator----------------------------------------------*/
        
    case 2:                                          
        cout<<"Section of increment decrement operatotrs\n";
        cout<<"Enter The Operand\n";
        cin>>op3;
        cout<<"Enter the operator(+ or -)\n";
        cin>>sign;
        cout<<"if you want to Start calculation press small 's'\ntype 'end' to end programe\n";
        cin>>dec2;
        
        if(dec2=="s")
        {
            goto start2;
        }
        else
        {
            goto end2;
        }
        
start2: 
        switch (sign)
        {
        case '+':
            op3=op3+1;
            cout<<"The incremented value is "<<op3<<"\n";
            break;
            
        case '-':     
            op3=op3-1;
            cout<<"The decremented value is \n"<<op3<<"\n";
            break;
            
        default:
            cout<<"enter a valid operator\n\n";
            break;       
        }
    
        cout<<"Press 'C' to clear screen and do more operations\n Enter end to end programe\n";
        cin>>clear;
        if (clear=="c")
        {
            system("cls");
            goto restart;
        }
        exit(0);
    
        break;
        /*----------------------------------------------Section of logical statements----------------------------------------------*/
    case 3:                                                      
        cout<<"section of logical statements\n";
        
        cout<<"Enter first expression in brackets '()'\n";
        cin>>exp1;
        istringstream(exp1)>>exper1; 
                
        cout<<"Type '&&' or '||' \n";
        cin>>sign2;
        
        cout<<"Enter second expression in brackets '()'\n";
        cin>>exp2;
        istringstream(exp2)>>exper2;
    
        cout<<"if you want to Start calculation press small 's'\ntype 'end' to end programe\n";
        cin>>dec3;
        if(dec3=="s")
        {
            goto start3;
        }
        else
        {
            goto end3;
        }
    
start3: 
        if (sign2=="&&")
        {
            answer=exper1&&exper2;
            if (answer==0)
            {
                cout<<"The experrssion evalutes to false\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"The experession evaluates to ture\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            answer=exper1||exper2;
            if (answer==0)
            {
                cout<<"The experrssion evalutes to false\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"The experession evaluates to ture\n";
            }            
        }
        cout<<"Press 'C' to clear screen and do more operations\n Enter end to end programe\n";
        cin>>clear;
        if (clear=="c")
        {
            system("cls");
            goto restart;
        }
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"enter any valid option\n";
     }
end:
end2:
end3: 
    return 0;
}
```

I am making a simple program which takes two relational expressions from user and use a logical operator to evaluate both of them. I used sstream to convert string into int but i think i am doing it wrong as it only evaluates the int to 0.I just want to get the evaluation of the string and the answer of it whether its 0 or 1 stored into the int data type.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include more context? The code you posted doesn't show the declarations or types of `exp1`, `exper1`, etc.

Comment: Reduce the problem. If you are having difficulty taking a number in a stringstream and obtaining a non-zero `int` from it, then make a program/example showing _that_ problem and nothing else. All the `if` statements and console output don't seem to be relevant to your problem. We also cannot see the input. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry it was my first post

Comment: Could you also add example input, expected output, and actual output? That would help tremendously.

Comment: I have posted all the code.

Comment: It looks like you're hoping the standard stream API will parse and evaluate an expression like "(1*2+3)" into a float. It's not that powerful, it can only parse single values. You'll have to manually extract values token by token and do the calculation yourself.

Comment: So if I enter (5>3) in a string and convert it into a int so it won't work right? I have to take 3 values from user both operands and operators and perform calculation on them?

Comment: `goto` usage :-/ better to use sub-function in your case.

Comment: @WaseeqAhmed That's correct.

Comment: ***If*** using goto at all, don't define three labels for one and the same location (end, end2, end 3), you can jump to the same label from multiple locations...